# 301 Redirects for 9k pages in a single site in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I was requested to create about 9k 301 redirects in Apache for a new site architecture, and I would like to know if anybody has any information on how to automate the process without having to create each redirect manually in the .htaccess or httpd.conf files.

For example the redirects will be something like this:

```
Redirect permanent /websitea /website-a
Redirect permanent /websitea/homepage/ /website-a/home-page
Redirect permanent /websitea/aboutus/ /website-a/about-us
Redirect permanent /websiteb/homepage/ /website-b/home-page
```

In other words the plan is to add a hyphen between each word in the directory to help with SEO.

Comment: I don't see a way to automate this in `.htaccess` without somehow detecting word boundaries. How will the computer know where hyphens belong? However, you might find [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) useful. See [Bulk 301 redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147394/bulk-301-redirect-from-htaccess).

Comment: If there are some specific rules for parts of the transformation, you might write a script, which creates .htaccess file(s).

Comment: I think the only rule would be to break up the directory's name by using  dictionary words on the script, but I think there might be a huge chance for it not to detect the words correctly.